# Как в boostrap 4 прибить объект к концу страници?

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap4

У меня есть навбар и мне нужно его прикрепить к концу страници как это сделать?
Уточнение не концу экрана, а концу страници. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<footer class="footer">your html</footer>
```

Comment: На сколько я знаю fixed-bottom привязывается элемент к низу экрана, а не концу страници.

Comment: @GTR По вашему вопросу непонятно, что нужно. К низу страницы, это как?

Comment: Тоесть к концу страници.

Comment: @GTR Пример скрином не приведете?

Comment: Вот пример скрином

Comment: При сроле я могу увидеть её половину, а могу полностью(она не привязана к моему экрану)

Comment: @GTR sticky footer?

Comment: Да как это сделать? Извините за плохо сформулированый вопрос.

Comment: @GTR `<footer class="footer"></footer>`